# MS Word SaveAs File Dialog with filters

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to save a custom file from VBA code under Microsoft Word. Is there an appropriate SaveAs dialog in Word VBA? What I need from this dialog:

1. to specify a custom filter;
2. to select a file that (probably) does not exist;
3. use Word VBA only if possible.

Solutions I found on this site:

1. Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs). Doesn't allow to specify a custom filter.
2. Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker). Doesn't allow to select a file that does not exists (this is a File Open dialog, not a File SaveAs one).
3. Application.GetSaveAsFilename. Works in Excel, but absent in Word.
4. Using Windows API. I want to avoid this if it is possible.
5. Calling an Excel application from Word VBA and use GetSaveAsFilename. Ugly solution. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Is Word Interop an acceptable alternative to you ? If so you can use SaveAs of the Document class.

Comment: Document.SaveAs just saves a specified Word document to filename specified as parameter (no dialog displayed). I need to ASK user for a filename to save some custom data (to be precise, to save some options for my Word addon).